# How to download the attachment from confluence page with powershell script?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

How to download the attachment from confluence page with **powershell script** ?

Comment: Please include more details, including something you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget --user myname --password mypassword "https://mysite.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/1841544/US_export_policy.jar"
```

OR

```
wget --header="Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx" "https://mysite.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/1841544/US_export_policy.jar"
```